# How can I auto-refresh a Vaadin Grid?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, vaadin

I have a grid with `Vaadin 8.0.0.beta` and `Java 8`.  The grid has various search filters and when the user clicks the search button, I simply execute the "refresh()" method.

For various reasons, the client wants the grid to refresh every 5 minutes automatically.  The grid will be displayed in a sort of dashboard view.

I tried annotating with @Scheduled (we're using `Spring` too) but I don't believe this is working because the Vaadin UI cannot accept a request from a different thread.

Also, we're not "pushing" the data to the client.  This is a simple polling system.

I don't know enough about the Vaadin UI to know if there is a better way.

Thanks.

Comment: Since you're not using push, you could add a [poll listener](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using+polling) to update your UI

Comment: That worked!  If you want to provide this as an answer I will accept.  For those that want to know, after I set the poll interval, I then added:   `addPollListener(event -> myview.refresh());`  Works a treat.

Comment: @Morfic Is there a reason to prefer this poll listener rather than use Vaadin’s Push feature? If Vaadin Push falls back to polling where WebSocket is not available, why not use Push? I'm not arguing, just genuinely curious and uneducated about this. Also, can you write up your comment as an Answer so this Question can be closed?

Comment: @BasilBourque It may sound weird but I'm not that educated about this either, meaning that I know about these alternatives, but did not need to go into details about each implementation as push worked fine for me so far. So perhaps my answer is not what you're looking for, nonetheless, I guess you could also think `why should we not always use Long instead of Byte`. Probably it depends on your requirements/restrictions and you also have to use another module in your app. Furthermore I'm not sure the `pollListener` will be triggered with the push-long-poling feature (haven't checked).

Comment: Also I imagined the OP will post and accept his own answer :-)